# Diagnosing submersible 24 VDC pump on SMPS

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, fluid-pump, underwater

I connected a [submersible 24 VDC, 1.2A water pump](https://marco-pumps.shop/marco-up500-submersible-pump-32-l-min-24-volt-16010013/) to a [constant voltage 24 VDC 100W LED Power Supply (SMPS)](https://www.hyrite.com/led-driver/indoor-mesh/eldv/indoor-led-power-supply-eldv-12e100b-100w-12v.html). As my user name shows, I have many of these LED power supplies in store. That's why I used one of them. (The link shows a 12V model, but it's a 24V of course.)
[Here is the general datasheet for the 24V series.](https://www.hyrite.com/fileuploader/download/download/?d=1&file=custom%2Fupload%2FFile-1414031257.pdf)

It worked during the first tests. Then it didn't work, then worked again and now it doesn't work anymore. The green indicator led on the SMPS is blinking which indicates an over current or a short circuit condition.
I expected that the SMPS could see the pump as a short circuit and refuses to turn on. However, as it worked during the first tests, I'm not sure.

I took my multi-meter: There are 3 Ohms between the V+ and the V- cables going to the pump. Measured after being disconnected from the SMPS.

The cables are 25m long.  There are four solid cables 2.5mm (or 14 AWG): two for V+, two for V-, on the first 20m. The last 5m are flexible 1.5mm (16 AWG) cables soldered to the cable of the pump and to the large cables. There is no connector, everything is soldered, until the SMPS terminal block.

The problem is that the connection between the (very short) pump cable and the flexible cable prolonging it is under water. I used thermally  shrinkable solder sleeves and doubled it with another thermally shrinkable sleeve.
Because everything is soldered, it's complicated to disassemble the installation. I want to avoid this work if the problem is not there.

3 Ohms is very small. Theoretically it should be about 10x more (but my knowledge in electric motors is very limited).

My question is: Does these 3 ohms indicate a short circuit, caused by infiltration of water or some other defect, or a damage to the pump, or is it normal and the SMPS simply, doesn't support powering the pump?

Comment: Which LED supply it is and does it have a data sheet or a manual? Does the pump have a data sheet or a manual? If they don't have specs then you don't know if the supply can drive the load. Theoretically the 3 ohms means very little, but the pump has a motor and motors tend to take say 10x the rated current when they start so 3 ohms could be correct. The pump is fused for 2.5A though.

Comment: I can’t say with certainty but it’s quite possible that the pump presents 3ohms as a ‘cold’ load - that would draw 8A at startup which doesn’t seem excessive.  Your LED power supply might well see this as an overload though.  This could be compounded by the long cable run meaning that the motor will be sluggish to start up and so the surge current may be drawn for longer than it would otherwise.  The startup load may well depend on the position at which the motor happens to stop, so intermittent startup is quite foreseeable.

Comment: Justme There is no data sheet for the pump and for the SMPS, I should ask the supplier if they have one. I know it uses flyback controller with over current and short circuit protection. I'm positive these protections works as intended.

Comment: Frog thanks for the comment. Indeed the very first test was made in the workshop with short cables. The other tests on the outdoor installation and it it seemed to work except one time and now. The position of the motor and the length of the cable could explain this.

Comment: Added datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, inrush current (stalled, drawing LRA (Locked Rotor Amperes)) causes the SMPS to brown out before the motor comes up to speed.  Simply get a somewhat overrated power supply and it should start up fine.

Erratic behavior can be due to several reasons: if the secondary side is switched, the SMPS's output capacitors deliver an initial kick, which nudges the motor; once in motion, the motor's resistance seems higher (actually it's generating some voltage, but I mean in terms of what the SMPS sees) and it might be just enough for the SMPS to continue uninterrupted, or to brown out and restart, giving another kick, and so on, and perhaps the motor keeps spinning just long enough for it to catch.  It should be harder to start up from cold (primary side switched), but the startup current may be higher than the steady-state current limit (a typical behavior of flyback supplies), and the same behavior applies (startup pulse nudges the motor, if it's spinning more each cycle, it may fully start up).

This also isn't a reliable test, because the motor may eventually get gummed up with, you know, silt, algae, whatever, friction rises, and what seemed reliable before, eventually fails to start.  You should choose, say, 50-100% extra capacity to account for this, above whatever value seems to start reliably.

Note that the motor is designed to run from a battery, so it could draw quite a bit of current at startup, and be limited only by fusing.  Which doesn't amount to much on short time scales -- at a current of a few times the rating (evidently triple, about 8A stalled, versus 2.5A rating), most fuses take some seconds to open.  So the motor is safely either started up, or stalled and cooking, by then, and a fuse is adequate protection.

For SMPS, I would recommend going towards the worst-case condition, a 24V supply of 5 to 10A -- likely to start, or indeed guaranteed to start up, with the 3 ohm load when stationary.  This also delivers enough current to clear the 2.5A fuse in case of stall or

If you have the option of an unregulated linear power supply, that will also be suitable, with a lower amperage rating -- without any active circuitry, they're fuse limited only, and the motor's fusing rating applies.  You can also build one yourself, using a (mains-frequency) transformer, rectifier and electrolytic capacitor.  You'd need an 18V, 3 to 5A transformer, a 10A+ bridge (Graetz) rectifier (25-35A types are regularly available with 1/4" QC terminals, easy to wire up), and 2200 to 4700µF rated 35-50V (any type will do).  Wire the transformer to the rectifier '~' terminals, plus to plus to plus, minus to minus to minus, and put a switch and fuse on the primary side.

A current-limiting startup circuit might also be used; simplest would probably be a series resistor or NTC, shunted by timer relay (these are readily available at 24V).  The resistor needs to be large enough that the SMPS doesn't shut down in the time the motor starts up, and small enough that the motor still spins (enough torque to exceed static friction).  It's not clear how much current the motor might need to start up, but I would try resistors on par with the motor, so, a few ohms.  This relaxes the SMPS amperage requirement

There are also some types of SMPS that may offer more startup/inrush current, though if it's long enough to make a motor spin, that's hard to say.

To summarize, some SMPS have more startup current than others; the motor may start up erratically depending on how it's bumped around during startup; and some (non-switching) supplies can deliver excess current in much the same way a battery, or the mains, can.

Water ingress:

Even salt water is unlikely to pass this much current, at least unless the wires were completely bare.  I doubt that's the problem here.

Any leakage to the connections will cause damage eventually, due to electrolysis: the positive connection will become oxidized and eroded.  This is one advantage to AC power: electrolysis is balanced on average, and corrosion is very slow.  If this is a concern (or you find it's failed in this way some months or years later), you might consider an AC motor instead.  Also, try to get long enough pigtails on the motor that they can be kept out of water, and then make extensions through air (and seal them well anyway).

You may also be interested in another type of heat shrink: the inside is coated in hot-melt glue, so that, on top of the tube conforming to the joint/wires, space is filled up by a tacky compound.

Joints can additionally be wrapped in self-agglomerating rubber tape, or even potted inside of an enclosure (likely severe overkill just for outdoors use, but it would do the job, lol; it's standard for deep/underwater application).

Comment: Thank you very much for this long explanation. Indeed: when I tested by switching the primary side of the SMPS, it failed to start but when I switched the secondary, the pump started. At least during the first several tests but not now anymore. Maybe because it requires already a few amperes more to start than when it was completely new. The SMPS is intended to stay on permanently and the pump to be turned on the secondary side by a MOSFET. I guess the MOSFET should also be rated 8A min. So far it's rated 2.3A and I was even surprised it didn't fail.

Answer (score 3):

In a DC permanent magnet motor the current I=(Vs-Eb)/Ra Vs is the supply voltage, Eb is the back EMF and Ra is the armature resistance.

The back EMF is proportional to motor speed at 0 motor speed the back EMF is 0 so the current is at a maximum. As the motor speeds up the back EMF rises and the current drops.

What this all means for you is that your motor will take a large surge of current as it starts up. Measuring the DC resistance of the motor will allow you to calculate the maximum value of this current as I=V/R in your case 24 V/3 Ohms = 8 amps. Your supply will need to be able to supply this surge.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. Problem is I'm not sure whether 3 Ohms is normal for this motor or if it results from poor isolation between cables or some other defect. The pump is new. Little used. But it worked a little bit without water (I don't know how bad it is to run without water for this model)

Comment: It is not unusual for a dc motor to take 5-10x its running current at startup so 3 Ohms is not unreasonable.

Comment: @Tim Williams and you were right: I replaced the 100W 4A supply by a 150W 6A and the pump started correctly already 3x (I have to wait for the water tank to be full before testing). I will see how it does long term. The 6A supply is probably tolerating 8A for short durations. I heavily underestimated the start up surge.